# Python no json object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, decode

I'm trying to create a simple login into a "Kahoot!" quiz .
First thing i'm trying to do is load from "https://kahoot.it/#/" JSON objects so i could fill the form in it (i tried to fill the form using 'mechenize' but its seems to support only html forms).
when im running the next script im getting exception that json could not be decoded:

```
import urllib, json
url = "https://kahoot.it/#/"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

output:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any ideas? ,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`type(response.read())` is `str`, representing the `HTML` of the page. Obviously it's not a valid `JSON` therefore you are getting that error.

**EDIT** If you are trying to login to that page, it is possible with `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://kahoot.it/#/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# finding the text field and 'typing' the game pin
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputSession"]').send_keys('your_game_pin')
# finding and clicking the sumbit button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/form/button').click()
```

Comment: so what is the right way to load json from this website?

Comment: In order to load JSON from the website, it needs to send you a response containing JSON.  It doesn't seem to be the case. If you are trying to login to that page, it is possible with `selenium`.

Comment: Thank you, any other idea how can i get the form so i could fill it with python?